# How to solve this system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I had a system of differential equations and I ended up in this.

$$4x+2y+4z=0$$
$$2x+y+2z=0$$
$$4x+2y+4z=0$$

I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(x,-2x-2z,z)$

Comment: There's always taking the null space...

Comment: Would you know what to do if you ended up with just one equation, $2x+y+2z=0$?

Answer (score 5):

Note that your system of equations is actually a single equation in various avatars. (i.e.) one is scalar multiple of the other. Put another way, these equations convey the same information, nothing new!

$$4x+2y+4z=0 \iff 2(2x+y+2z=0) \iff 4x+2y+4z=0$$
Since there are three unknowns, and only one equations, two parameters are required to fix a solution. We can have a parametric solution as follows:

Set $x=\lambda$ and $y=\mu$. Then, $$2\lambda+\mu+2z=0 \implies z=\dfrac{-2\lambda-\mu}{2}$$

Hence, the triplet  $(\lambda,\mu,\dfrac{-2\lambda-\mu}{2})$ with $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb R$ is a solution to your system.

Comment: That's kind of confusing. Firstly you mention that there is one equation and then you mention that there are two.

Comment: That was a typo! I am sorry. I fixed it now!